# Manipulation of a vector equation does not produce the desired result

Tags: matrices

What is wrong with the following argument?

Let $H:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map given by
\begin{equation*}
x=H(y)\quad\iff\quad\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is an $m$-by-$n$ real matrix.
Then, why the following does not hold in general?
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{x}&=\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}\\
(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{x}&=\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{x}&=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{x}&=(\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T)^{-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y},
\end{align*}
implying thereby that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{I}_m=(\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T)^{-1},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{I}_m$ is the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

Please note that:

1. In the second line I multiplied both sides by $\mathbf{H}^T$.
2. In the third line I multiplied both sides by $(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}$.
3. In the fourth line I multiplied both sides by $\mathbf{H}$.
4. In the last line I multiplied both sides by $(\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T)^{-1}$.

However, this conclusion seems not to be true. For instance, take:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{H}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{5\times3}.
\end{equation*}
Then we get:
\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\neq\mathbf{I}_5.
\end{equation*}
In fact, it is easy to see that $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T$ is non-invertible.

To be honest, I am not sure where the argument went wrong. So if you have any ideas why I cannot manipulate the equation in such a way, please let me know.

Thank you,
Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T$ is invertible when you take the inverse.  It certainly cannot be, for $\mathbf{H}$ has rank at most $3$.  If $m\ne n$ considerations of rank show that either $\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H}$ is not invertible or $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H})^{-1}\mathbf{H}^T$ is not invertible.